# How to search through archived files with Perl

Tags: perl, search, file-io, compression

What is your preferred method for reading through the contents of zipped directories with Perl ?

Comment: are you trying to look at the directory listing or the content of the files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several modules on CPAN for working with various archive formats (zip, tar, etc.), the one you're probably after is [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Archive-Zip-1.24/lib/Archive/Zip.pm).

Comment: When you post links to (search.)CPAN, please make sure you point to the author and version agnostic URL so it always points to the latest version of the module. In this case, that would be: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::Zip

Answer (score 4):

Archive::Zip

```
require Archive::Zip;
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($somefile);
for($zip->memberNames()) {
  print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the contents of a .tar.gz archive

```
open(DIR_LISTING, "gzip -dc concert25.tgz | tar -tf -|") || die;
while (<DIR_LISTING>) {
   print;
}
close (DIR_LISTING);
```